# How do I implement the find on an IList and update object properties on the objects that are found

Tags: .net, vb.net, find, ilist

I am declaring an IList:

```
Dim OrigVendors as IList
OrigVendors = new List( of IVendors)
```

I populate the OrigVendors variable and what I want to do is find all the objects that have the ID I am looking for.  Then I need to update a property on that object for only the ones found. Is this do able with an IList or do I need to use some other type of collection?  I am using VB.net

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are making a distinction between the [non-Generic version of IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx) and the Generic [List class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx), then you can filter on specific properties.

Because the IList interface does not derive from the [Generic IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) (but rather, the [non-Generic version of IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.aspx)), you can't use many of the extension methods on the [Enumerable class in the System.Linq namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx).

However, if you know that the non-Generic IList implementation contains *only* implementations of IVendors, then what you *can* do is call the [Cast extension method on IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx) like so:

```
Dim typedVendors = OrigVendors.Cast(of IVendors)
```

Once you have the typed IEnumerable(of IVendors), you can use any of the LINQ methods you choose to filter out the sequence and perform operations on the items.